# Playing background audio failure

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I want to play background audio in a windows phone application.
The following code suggested in MSDN dosn't work :

```
const string audio = "http://audio.radio24.it/radio24_audio/2012/121028-140-caratteri.mp3";
            AudioTrack canzone = new AudioTrack(new Uri(audio, UriKind.Absolute), "", "", "", new Uri(audio, UriKind.Absolute));
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = canzone;
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
```

`The BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayState` persist to Unknown and no sound is reproduced. I have to use absolute uri.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with Fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the **AudioPlayerAgent**?
Try to read the example in this website [Charles Petzold's Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/magazine/hh781030.aspx)
For more advanced information about Background Audio Player in Windows Phone 7.5
Check this website [Windows Phone COE's Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpukcoe/archive/2012/02/09/background-audio-in-windows-phone-7-5-part-1.aspx)
I found these two very useful when I implement my BAP

Update if you have more questions. Good luck:)